# using variables within a SELECT option php

Tags: php

I'm collecting data from a form into a session, on another form, I use a few variables to feed a SELECT option, which works as I want. as shown here

```
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="householder" name="householder">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A"><?php echo $_SESSION["name1"];?></option>
    <option value="B"><?php echo $_SESSION["name2"];?></option>
    <option value="C"><?php echo $_SESSION["name3"];?></option>
    <option value="D"><?php echo $_SESSION["name4"];?></option> </select>
```

My issue is how I can change this, currently if within the form, any names are left blank then when it comes to the SELECT, there is a blank line for every option blank, is there a way to change this and if a variable is blank then ignore and use the next variable, this would then make my SELECT look tidy

Comment: Just put an if condition.

Comment: IMO You  should use some collection to store the options. Iterate over it to remove not-required and then iterate to display. Or directly put a check before displaying the option while iterating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should consider using an array instead of a series of uniquely named session variable names, e.g.:

```
$_SESSION['names'] = array('A' => 'First', 'B' => 'Second');
```

Then you can loop over them with `foreach` instead. Also the benefit of that would be you can use the `array_filter` function ([documentation](http://uk.php.net/array_filter)) to filter out empty values from your array of names before looping over them:

```
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="householder" name="householder">
<option value=""></option>
<?php 
$options = array_filter($_SESSION['names']);
foreach ($options as $option_value => $option_name): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $option_value; ?>"><?php echo $option_name;?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["name1"]) && $_SESSION["name1"]!='') {?><option value="A"><?php echo $_SESSION["name1"];?></option><?php } ?>
```

this for every line/option of your select

Answer (score 1):

use an if statement to check if your variable exists.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION["name1"])) : ?>
    <option value="C"><?php echo $_SESSION["name1"];?></option>
<?php endif; ?>
```